# Brother MFC-J870DW network printer drivers

Tags: 13.04, printing, brother

I have a brother MFC-J870DW printer that is attached to my network. I have had no success in finding out how the thing works on my Ubuntu 13.04 64Bit computer. I am wondering if I am just a dummy with printers or if it cant print at all any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same printer and installed two .deb files to get it to work with Ubuntu (both 12.04 and 13.04).  Ubuntu does not have the printer driver by default so I had to go to the Brother Website, download the LPR driver (.deb file) and the Cups Wrapper driver (.deb file) for this printer.  
Here is the link [Brother Printer Driver Download Page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-J870DW)

 (I found the link by.....
     - Searching for **brother linux printer drivers**
     - Clicking on **Download Link** under Brother Solutions Center : Brother Driver for Linux Distributions Link
     - **Under MFC** clicking on the **MFC-J870DW** Link which will simply scroll you down to the MFC-J870DW
        Once you scroll down you will see table format, make sure you select from the files under the MFC-J870DW section, you will see other sections for other printers above and below the MFC-J870DW section

> ### MFC-J870DW

LPR driver                           rpm  
cupswrapper driver  rpm 
LPR driver                            deb 
cupswrapper driver  deb

- Now you will need to download and install the LPR driver before you install the Cups Wrapper Driver otherwise. Make sure you **download the two deb files** for the correct printer, **NOT the rpm files**.

**NOTE**: You must first **install the LPR driver BEFORE you install the Cups Wrapper Driver.** If you try to install the Cups Wrapper Driver first, you will get "Dependency not satisfiable".

- If you run the .deb files by double clicking in Nautilus (The File Viewer) it should open the file in Ubuntu Software Center and allow you to install. When you install, you will get a message that the **Package "is of bad quality"**, **CLICK ON the "Ignore and Install" button.**

After you install both, under printers, you will probably not see a printer icon, click on the **Add Button**, you should be able to see the the Printer under Network Printers since it is a Wifi Printer, you will see it listed twice, at least one of them will work.

If neither of them work.. **ON THE PRINTER ITSELF..** 
- **Touch the Wi-Fi Button** on the Screen Display (If the screen display is black, touching it should light it up).

 
 - **Touch the TCP/IP Button** 
 
 - **Write Down the IP Address** which will be a set of four numbers with dots between them
 
 - Go back to **Ubuntu** and **click on Add Button under Printing**

 
 - You can enter the Pritner IP Address in the  URI Section and then continue to setup the printer for Ubuntu.

I hope I gave you enough information to get setup.

Comment: After installing the drivers and adding the printers, I had to manually select the printer driver in the CUPS management website (http://localhost:631).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem i just used this link

http: //localhost:631 (remove the space)

click on "adding printer and classes"

then add printer

it should work after

good luck